# Fifa 23 PC Daily login SBC disappeared

Tags: fifa-23

As the Daily login SBC was reintroduced in Fifa 23, I activated it for many days (I succeeded the 22 days streak objectives).
Now, as for 3 days, it has not appeared.

Does it mean that it won't appear again only in the next season?